# Parsing relatively structured text files in python and inserting in mongodb

Tags: python, regex

Testbed:  ABC123

```
Image  : FOOBAR
Keyword: heredity
Date   : 6/27
Other  : XYZ suite crash

     Suite  : XYZ, crash post XYZ delivery
         Failure: 
         Reason : 
         Known  :

         Failure: 
         Reason : 
         Known  : 

         Type   :

         Notes  :
```

Testbed: ABC456

```
Image  : FOOBAR
Keyword: isolate
Date   :6/27
Other  : 3 random failures in 3 different test suites

     Suite  : LMO Frag
         Failure: jumbo_v4_to_v6 
         Reason : ?
         Known  : ?

         Type   :

         Notes  : 

    Suite  : XYZ suite
         Failure:  XYZ_v4_to_v4v
         Reason : failed to receive expected packets
         Known  : ?

         Type   :

         Notes  : 

    Suite  : RST
         Failure: RST_udp_v4_to_v6 
         Reason : failed to receive expected packets
         Known  : ?

         Type   :

         Notes  : 

Image  : BARFOO
Keyword: repugnat
Date   : 6/26
Other  : 

     Suite  : PQR test
         Failure: unable to destroy flow - flow created without ppx flow id
         Reason : SCRIPT issue
         Known  : maybe?

         Type   : embtest

         Notes  : 

    Suite  : UVW suite
         Failure:  8 failures in UVW duplicate - interworking cases not working!
         Reason : ?
         Known  : ?

         Type   :

         Notes  :
```

---

I am trying to create documents of the type

```
{
        "_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "platform" : "ABC123",
        "image" : "FOOBAR",
        "keyword" : "parricide",
        "suite" : [
                {
                        "name" : "RST (rst_only_v6v_to_v6)",
                        "notes" : "",
                        "failure" : "flow not added properly",
                        "reason" : "EMBTEST script issue",
                        "known" : "yes?",
                        "type" : ""
                }
        ]
}
```

Where each document is unique based on the testbed, platform and image.

I have tried using regex and came up with something of this format but this is prone to human error in creating the structured text in which case this would fail due to its dependencies:

```
        for iter in content:
            if re.match(r"\s*testbed",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                testbed = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                if result_doc['platform'] == None:
                    result_doc['platform'] = testbed 

            if re.match(r"\s*image",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                image = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                if result_doc['image'] == None:
                    result_doc['image'] = image

            if re.match(r"\s*keyword",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                keyword = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                if result_doc['keyword'] == None:
                    result_doc['keyword'] = keyword 
                key = str(testbed)+'-'+str(image)+'-'+str(keyword)
                if prev_key == None:
                    prev_key = key
                if key != prev_key: #if keys differ, then add to db
                    self.insert(result_doc)
                    prev_key = key
                    result_doc = self.getTemplate("result") #assign new document template
                    result_doc['platform'] = testbed 
                    result_doc['image'] = image
                    result_doc['keyword'] = keyword
                result_doc['_id'] = key 

            if re.match(r"\s*suite",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                suitename = iter.split(':')[1].strip()

            if re.match(r"\s*Failure",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                suitefailure = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                result_suite = self.getTemplate("suite") # assign new suite template
                result_suite['name'] = suitename
                result_suite['failure'] = suitefailure

            if re.match(r"\s*Reason",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                suitereason = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                result_suite['reason'] = suitereason

            if re.match(r"\s*Known",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                suiteknown = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                result_suite['known'] = suiteknown

            if re.match(r"\s*type",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                suitetype = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                result_suite['type'] = suitetype

            if re.match(r"\s*Notes",iter,re.IGNORECASE):
                suitenotes = iter.split(':')[1].strip()
                result_suite['notes'] = suitenotes
                result_doc['suite'].append(result_suite)

        self.insert(result_doc) #Last document to be inserted
```

Is there a better way to do this than match on the next tag to create a new document??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is definitely a better, more robust way to do this. One would use a hash table, or python "dictionary," to store the key value pairings provided in an input file and do some formatting to print them out in the desired output format.

```
# Predefine some constants / inputs
testbed_dict = { "_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "platform" : "ABC456" }
inputFile = "ABC456.txt"

with open(inputFile,"r") as infh:
  inputLines = infh.readlines()
  image_start_indices = [inputLines.index(x) for x in inputLines if x.split(":")[0].strip() == "Image"]
  image_end_indices = [x-1 for x in image_start_indices[1:]]
  image_end_indices.append(len(inputLines)-1)
  image_start_stops = zip(image_start_indices, image_end_indices)
  suite_start_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(inputLines) if x.split(":")[0].strip() == "Suite"]
  suite_end_indices = [i+1 for i, x in enumerate(inputLines) if x.split(":")[0].strip() == "Notes"]
  suite_start_stops = zip(suite_start_indices,suite_end_indices)
  for image_start_index, image_stop_index in image_start_stops:
    suiteCount = 1
    image_suite_indices, suites, image_dict = [], [], {}
    for start, stop in suite_start_stops:
      if start >= image_stop_index or image_start_index >= stop:
        continue
      image_suite_indices.append((start,stop))
    suites = [inputLines[x:y] for x, y in image_suite_indices]
    header_end_index = min([x for x, y in image_suite_indices])
    for line in inputLines[image_start_index:header_end_index]:
      if line.strip() == "":
        continue
      key, value = (line.split(":")[0].strip().lower(), line.split(":")[1].strip())
      image_dict[key] = value
    for suite in suites:
      suite_dict = {}
      for line in suite:
        if line.strip() == "":
          continue
        key, value = (line.split(":")[0].strip().lower(), line.split(":")[1].strip())
        suite_dict[key] = value
      image_dict["suite "+str(suiteCount)] = suite_dict
      suiteCount += 1
    with open(image_dict["image"]+".txt","w") as outfh:
      outfh.write('{\n')
      for key, value in testbed_dict.iteritems():
        outfh.write('\t"'+key+'" : "'+testbed_dict[key]+'"\n')
      for key, value in image_dict.iteritems():
        if 'suite' in key:
          continue
        else:
          outfh.write('\t"'+key+'" : "'+value+'",\n')
      for key, value in image_dict.iteritems():
        if 'suite' not in key:
          continue
        else:
          outfh.write('\t"suite" : [\n\t\t{\n')
          for suitekey, suitevalue in value.iteritems():
            outfh.write('\t\t\t"'+suitekey+'" : "'+str(suitevalue)+'",\n')
          outfh.write("\t\t}\n")
          outfh.write("\t],\n")
      outfh.write('}\n')
```

The above code expects to be run in the same directory as an input file (i.e. ' inputFile = "ABC456.txt" '), and writes a variable number of output files depending on how many "images" are present in the input -- in the case of your ABC456 the outputs written would be "FOOBAR.txt" and "BARFOO.txt". For example, if "ABC456.txt" contains the text contents of the section "Testbed: ABC456" in your question above, then the outputs will be the following.

BARFOO.txt

```
{
    "platform" : "ABC456"
    "_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "keyword" : "repugnat",
    "image" : "BARFOO",
    "other" : "",
    "date" : "6/26",
    "suite" : [
        {
            "notes" : "",
            "failure" : "8 failures in UVW duplicate - interworking cases not working!",
            "reason" : "?",
            "known" : "?",
            "suite" : "UVW suite",
            "type" : "",
        }
    ],
    "suite" : [
        {
            "notes" : "",
            "failure" : "unable to destroy flow - flow created without ppx flow id",
            "reason" : "SCRIPT issue",
            "known" : "maybe?",
            "suite" : "PQR test",
            "type" : "embtest",
        }
    ],
}
```

FOOBAR.txt

```
{
    "platform" : "ABC456"
    "_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "keyword" : "isolate",
    "image" : "FOOBAR",
    "other" : "3 random failures in 3 different test suites",
    "date" : "6/27",
    "suite" : [
        {
            "notes" : "",
            "failure" : "RST_udp_v4_to_v6",
            "reason" : "failed to receive expected packets",
            "known" : "?",
            "suite" : "RST",
            "type" : "",
        }
    ],
    "suite" : [
        {
            "notes" : "",
            "failure" : "XYZ_v4_to_v4v",
            "reason" : "failed to receive expected packets",
            "known" : "?",
            "suite" : "XYZ suite",
            "type" : "",
        }
    ],
    "suite" : [
        {
            "notes" : "",
            "failure" : "jumbo_v4_to_v6",
            "reason" : "?",
            "known" : "?",
            "suite" : "LMO Frag",
            "type" : "",
        }
    ],
}
```

The code above works but has some caveats -- it doesn't preserve ordering of the lines, but assuming you're just sticking this JSON into mongoDB certainly ordering doesn't matter. Also you would need to modify it to handle some redundancies -- if the "Suite" line has redundant info nested under it (e.g. multiple "Failure" lines, like in your ABC123 example) all but one is ignored. Hopefully you get a chance to look through the code, figure out how it's working, and modify it to meet whatever your needs are.

Cheers.